# How do I add fadein or fadeout animation when doing addClass or removeClass on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am basically trying to change classes of a bootstrap 4 navbar with the following jquery when there is a scroll but this doesnt seem to be working

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

  if (scroll >= 100) {
    $(".navbar")
      .removeClass("navbar-dark")
      .fadeOut("fast");
    $(".navbar")
      .addClass("navbar-light bg-light")
      .fadein("slow");
  } else {
    $(".navbar")
      .removeClass("navbar-light bg-light")
      .fadeOut("fast");
    $(".navbar")
      .addClass("navbar-dark")
      .fadein("slow");
  }
});
```

Comment: You're going to be triggering the `.fadeOut()` and `.fadeIn()` calls multiple times when you scroll, which probably causes issues with animation. What about simply toggling a class that changes the opacity (0 to 1 and vice versa)?

Comment: May I ask why the `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` at all? (And BTW it's `fadeIn`, not `fadein` - Use console to spot those simple errors)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You don't need two classes. Only *Default* styles and a *special* class.
- Don't use jQuery to do animations - Use [CSS3 and `transition`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/transition) instead
- Use [jQuery's `.toggleClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) Method
- Cache your selector Elements! The worst thing you can do is on every scroll-tick query the entire DOM to go search for a .class element/s - that's a too expensive operation.

```js
const $navbar = $('.navbar'); // Cache your elements!!

$(window).on('scroll', function() {
  const st = $(window).scrollTop();
  $navbar.toggleClass('is-scrolled', st >= 100);
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 300vh; /* DEMO to force scrollbars */
}


/* DEFAULT STYLE */
.navbar {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  transition: 0.4s;
  background: gold;  
}

/* SCROLLED STYLE */
.navbar.is-scrolled { 
  background: #888;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">NAVBAR</div>Scroll down...
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: what if i needed to toggle in between 2 classes? i am using bootstrap with 2 sets of navbar classes (navbar-light bg-light) and (navbar-dark)

Comment: If you're lucky enough to use a SCSS preprocessor - **@extend** those modifiers inside your defaults instead of polluting HTML class lists. (If you don't mind a bit heavier CSS file instead) - Or use jQuery like `.toggleClass('class-a class-b'`

Answer (score 0):

The [`.fadeOut()`](https://api.jquery.com/fadeout/) function of jQuery has a duration and a complete parameter. The complete parameter can be a function which is called whenever the fade out is finished. This way you can do something **after** the fadeOut is finished, like do the fadeIn that you want.

See the example below.

```
var $navbar = $(".navbar");
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
  if (scroll >= 100) {
    $navbar
      .removeClass("navbar-dark")
      .stop(true, true)
      .fadeOut("fast", function() {
        $navbar
          .addClass("navbar-light bg-light")
          .fadeIn("slow");
      });
  } else {
    $navbar
      .removeClass("navbar-light bg-light")
      .stop(true, true)
      .fadeOut("fast", function() {
        $navbar
          .addClass("navbar-dark")
          .fadeIn("slow");
      });
  }
});
```

But I would encourage to use CSS transitions for this cause since they are way easier to work with and most importantly, more performant than jQuery fade in and out.

### Edit

As Roko suggested, you should use the [`.stop()`](https://api.jquery.com/stop/) function to stop any current animation on the element where a `fadeIn` or `fadeOut` is running.

Comment: As you put it - it could result buggy. You should use `.stop()` to prevent animations buildups. And BTW we should not use jQuery any more to do animations (like the `fadeIn / fadeOut`), instead we should only assign a class and let the browser do the CSS3 `transition` for us.

Comment: Also, it's `fadeIn` not `fadein` - Thank you but why would I edit your answer? You can do it, c'mon.

Comment: `.stop(true, true)` , actually `.stop()` is quite enough.